# FLEX - adding items to s:list from recieved data from socket

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have s:list component in my MXML and a different actionsscript file which does the socket connection to the server.
Everytime a user is connecting to the server I'm sending to all clients the updated users in the server by sending strings of ports (port for each user).
Now, when the data gets to the client (to the action script file SocketData function), I want it to be added as an item to the s:List in the MXML file.
How do I do such thing ? what it's called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a *Bindable* `ArrayCollection` property inside the AS3 class that handles the socket connection.  Store the results from the socket call in this `ArrayCollection`.  Then, in the MXML, bind this property from the instance you use to the `dataprovider` property on your `<s:List>`.

Comment: That's working, but the dataprovider contains array of objects which each object has 5 data member and I want to represent each line in the s:List with the object data for example: row 1: TableId: 1 TableName: myfirstable MaxPlayers: 4 MinRank: 10 PasswordProtected: Yes

Comment: @Alon - One option is to write a custom item renderer for the List, then you could display all those things per item and have them formatted.  Otherwise, it sounds like you might be more interested in a [DataGrid](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html).  This, however, might entail you transform the Array into an Object, so that the entries have keys (eg, _tableID_, _tableName_, _maxPlayers_, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need to do something like this:

```
list.dataProvider = resultsFromSocketCall;
```

---

Update:  More info per Alon's request to use binding.

Create a Bindable variable, I'll use an ArrayCollection:

```
[Bindable]
public var myCollection : ArrayCollection;
```

Bind it to the dataProvider on the list:

```
<s:List dataProvider="{myCollection}" />
```

When you get the results back from your socket call; you can do something like this:

```
myCollection = resultsFromSocketCall;
```

Comment: The List is a MXML spark component <s:List>, how do I bind the results from the socket to it ?

Comment: @alon I updated my answer to demonstrate how one might do this with binding.  Although, I'm not sure why you'd use binding in this case.